# Columns Not Assigned Properly in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in a .csv file, which I am trying to extract and name its columns. I use the following code:

```
data_name = 'housing.csv'
column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX',
                                 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO',
                                 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']
data = pd.read_csv(data_name, names=column_names, error_bad_lines=False,
                   header=None)
```

The problem is that it assigns the titles to the wrong columns. Only the last column gets renamed and others are added, filled with NaN values. I have also tried using `rename` with similar results. Here is what `print(data.head())` Looks like:

```
                                                CRIM  ZN  ...  LSTAT  MEDV
0   0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65... NaN  ...    NaN   NaN
1   0.02731   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  6.4210  78... NaN  ...    NaN   NaN
2   0.02729   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  7.1850  61... NaN  ...    NaN   NaN
3   0.03237   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.9980  45... NaN  ...    NaN   NaN
4   0.06905   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  7.1470  54... NaN  ...    NaN   NaN
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text data is separated by spaces instead of commas.

You can try to explicitly tell `read_csv` to use one or more spaces as the field delimiter:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_name, names=column_names, error_bad_lines=False,
                   header=None, sep='\s+')
```

There's also an explicit `delim_whitespace` option in `read_csv` that does the same as the above. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **delim_whitespace: bool, default False**
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. `' '` or `'    '`) will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting `sep='\s+'`. If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the `delimiter` parameter.

Comment: Do you need to specify the separator as a raw string (`r'\s+'`)? @foglerit

Comment: @Todd: Good question. I just tested with and without using the raw string and found no difference in behavior. Is the behavior different for you?

Comment: Yes. I did notice it's different. Without the `r`, the Python interp treats the backslash as an escape. With the `r` it treats it as a valid regular expression statement. I have an example of using this same expr here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368867/7915759, you can try using read_csv() to convert the text I show there into a dataframe with and without the 'r'

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how python interprets backslashes in strings and raw strings. I meant if you see any difference between using it or not in `read_csv`. I just ran the example in your link **without** the `r` and it worked. Also, the `read_csv` docs suggest using `sep='\s+'`, not `sep=r'\s+'`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html -- check the option `delim_whitespace`.

Comment: Whether "it works" or not, '\s+' is a wrong regular expression. You need the 'r' in front of the string to tell the interp to regard backslashes as normal characters. Or, alternatively, you could put '\\s+'. @foglerit